# How to list all paths that are used for including header files in a Qt project?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I've imported a C++ project (Shrewsoft VPN) into Qt creator.

Some include statements fail, because the included file cannot be found e. g.

```
#include <openssl/rand.h>
```

I know where the `openssl/rand.h` file resides. But I don't know the paths Qt / C++ compiler looks for it.

Is there a way to get a list of all paths Qt searches for this header files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qt searches header files in 3 way,

The first search path is your compiler path, exp. With MSVC2015 it will search in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include

The second search path is your Qt version folder and linked Qt library, exp. With Qt5.9.2 and widgets library, it will search in C:\Qt\5.9.2\msvc2015_64\include\QtWidgets

The last search path is your external header path contain in your INCLUDEPATH var parsed with QMake.

For openssl in windows app you need to add

```
QT += core gui network
win32{
 LIBS += -LC:/OpenSSL-Win32/lib -lubsec
 INCLUDEPATH += C:/OpenSSL-Win32/include
}
```

to your project file, and replace C:/OpenSSL-Win32/ with your downloaded OpenSSL path.

Answer (score 4):

There are two things that influence the search path: The build environment and the project settings. The build environment is typically inherited from the system, and the project settings are defined in you .pro file

In Qt Create 4.3, you can see the build environment in
Project (on the left pane) > Build > Build Environment > Details > INCLUDE

But I recommend to add the include path in your project file. Add this in your .pro file:

```
INCLUDEPATH += (Base Path to openssl includes)
```

You may also need to extend the library search path for linking:

```
LIBS += -L(Path to openssl libs) -l(openssl lib name)
```

Comment: `Project (on the left pane) > Build > Build Environment > Details > INCLUDE` helped me a lot, because I don't have a .pro file in my project. I've put my path there, and everything worked like a charm.